# xhtmlrenderer/Flying Saucer - UTF-8 Encoding not working

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

I am using Flying Saucer and xhtmlrenderer to produce PDFs from a String-HTML-Code.

The Html-String is:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {

    font-family: 'Arial';

    src: url("fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF");

    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;

    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

    * { font-family: 'Arial'!important; }</style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p lang="de-DE" class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Kim, Sohyeun [</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Kim, Sohyŏn] </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">김소현</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><b>1993,</b></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"> Tang sidae ŭi hobok e kwanhan yŏn'gu </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">당시대의 호복에 관한 연구 </span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">/ The Study on the ‘Ho Bok (Chinese: Hu-Fu, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">胡服</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">)’ in the T’ang Dynasty. Ph. D. Dissertation, Ewha Woman’s University: Department of Clothing and Textiles. </span></font></p>
  <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><br /></p>
  <p lang="de-DE" class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><b>Keywords: </b></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Kucha, hairstyle, Book of Wei, Weishu, Old Book of Tang, Jiutangshu, clothing, costume, Great Tang Records on the Western Regions, Da Tang Xiyu ji, History of Northern Dynasties, Beishi.</span></font></p>
  <p lang="de-DE" class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><b>Notes: </b></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Information in parenthesis are supplemented by Ji Ho Yi. </span></font></p>
  <p lang="de-DE" class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><b>Summary: </b></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Costume of Kucha is treated in pp. 68–73, (1) K'uch'a, K'arasyarŭ ŭi poksik </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">쿠차</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">카라샤르의 복식 </span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">(Costume of Kucha, Karashar) under Na. Sŏyŏkpukto- K'uch'a, K'arasyarŭ, T'urŭp'an-ŭi poksik </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">나</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">. </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">서역북도</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">- </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">쿠차</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">카라샤르</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">투르판</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">-</span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">의 복식 </span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">(B. Costume of Northern Circuit of Western Regions (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Xiyu, </i></span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">西域</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">)-Kucha, Karashar, Turfan). Kim refers to various visual materials and Chinese literary materials. Following are excerpts of relevant passages from Kim’s dissertation:</span></font></p>
  <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><br /></p>
  <p lang="de-DE" class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><u>Hairstyle</u></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">:</span></font></p>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <p lang="de-DE" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Kim writes that Kucha’s custom of cutting one’s hair might have been influenced by the Persians. According to Chinese accounts of Persians in the </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Book of Wei</i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"> (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Weishu, </i></span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">魏書</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">) and the </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Old </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Book of Tang</i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"> (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Jiutangshu,</i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"> </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">舊</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">唐書</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">), it was typical for Persians to cut their hair. </span></font></p></li>
  </ul>
  <p lang="de-DE" style="line-height: 100%; margin-left: 0.64cm; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">(In volume 102 (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>juan </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">102, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">卷</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">102) of the </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Book of Wei</i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">, the relevant sentences are as follows: (According to) local custom, the men cut (their) hair, wear white leather hat. The shirt has a hole for the head (?), the sleeves open as they come closer to the bottom. There is also a headscarf, the borders are made of patterned garment. Women wear large coats and put on large skirts. Their hair is knotted at the front and draped in the back. They decorate (themselves) with golden and silver flowers, added with a string of beads in five colours, draped at the limbs. </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">其俗丈夫剪髮，戴白皮帽</span></font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">貫頭衫，</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">兩廂近下開之，</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">亦有巾</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">帔</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">，</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">緣以織成</span></font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">婦女服大衫，</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">披大</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">帔</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">，</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">其髮前</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">為</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">髻，</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">後披之，</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">飾以金銀花，</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">仍貫五色珠，</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">絡之於膊。</span></font><span lang="ko-KR">”</span></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">The account about Persian clothing in volume 198 (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>juan </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">198, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">卷</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">198) of </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Old Book of Tang </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">is similar, only more detailed. It mentions that the male headscarves of used often sappanwood-dye-colour (red-orange, I translated </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>sufang </i></span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">蘇方</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">as the name of tree, </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Biancaea sappan</i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">), blue and white colours.</span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB"> “</span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">多用蘇方</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">青</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">白色</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">為</span></font><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">之</span></font><span lang="ko-KR">”</span></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">)</span></font></p>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <p lang="de-DE" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm">“<font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Both men and women (of Kucha) cut hair and let them down, along with neck garment (?), only the king does not cut his hair, …, the king covers the neck with silk brocade, wears a silk brocade robe and golden jewelled belt, sits on a golden lion throne</span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="">男女皆剪髮垂與項齊</font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="">唯王不剪髮</font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">,…, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="">其王以錦蒙項</font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="">着錦袍</font><font face="Arial">金</font><font face="">寶帶</font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="">坐</font><font face="Arial">金</font><font face="">獅子牀</font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">.</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"> (Translation by Ji Ho Yi)</span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">”</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Old Book of Tang</i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"> (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Jiutangshu</i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">舊唐書</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">), volume 198 (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>juan </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">198, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">卷</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">198)</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"> </span></font></p></li>
   <li>
    <p lang="de-DE" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm">“<font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">服飾錦褐</span></font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">剪髮巾帽</span></font><span lang="ko-KR">”</span><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR"> </span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">(“Wears silk brocade and fur, cuts hair and wears headscarf-hat.”) </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Xuanzang, </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Great Tang Record of [Travels to] the Western Regions</i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"> </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">大唐西域記</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">(</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Da Tang Xiyu Ji. </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">According to Buswell, Robert E. Jr. and Lopez, Donald S., 2014, </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>The Princeton Dictionary of Buddhism. </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Princeton, N.J. and Oxford, United Kingdom: Princeton University Press, p. 224, this is “a travelogue of a pilgrimage to India by the Chinese translator and exegete Xuanzang (600/602–664) written in 646 at the request of the Tang emperor Taizong and edited by the monk Bianji (d. 652)…The </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Da Tang Xiyu ji </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">provides a comprehensive overview of the different countries that Xuanzang visited during his travels in India and Central Asia, offering detailed descriptions of the geography, climate, customs, languages, and religious practices of these various countries.”</span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">)</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">, volume 1 (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>juan </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">1, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">卷</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">1</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">) </span></font></p></li>
   <li>
    <p lang="de-DE" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Kim supposes that the King of Kucha did not cut his hair because Kucha was subjugated to Turks and followed Turkic custom. She refers to </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>History of Northern Dynasties </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">(</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Beishi, </i></span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">北史</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">), volume 97 (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>juan </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">97, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">卷</span></font><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR"> </span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">97), “the king’s head is bound with silk ribbon and it is let down to the back </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">其王頭繫綵帶</span></font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">垂之于後</span></font><span lang="ko-KR"> </span></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">(Translation by Ji Ho Yi)</span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">”</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">and </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Book of Wei </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">(</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>Weishu, </i></span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">魏書</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">), volume 102 (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>juan </i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">102, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">卷</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">102), </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">which writes “The king’s head is bound with silk ribbon and it is let down to the back. </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face=""><span lang="ko-KR">其王頭繫綵帶，垂之於後</span></font></span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">. </span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">(Translation by Ji Ho Yi)</span></font><font face=", serif"><span lang="en-GB">”</span></font></p></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><br /></p>
  <p lang="de-DE" class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><u>Collar: </u></span></font></p>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <p lang="de-DE" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Everted collars (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>fanling, </i></span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">翻領</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">) are found most often in Kizil wall paintings. </span></font></p></li>
   <li>
    <p lang="de-DE" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">A new form of collar, which has qualities of both everted collar (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>fanling, </i></span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">翻領</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">) and straight collar (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>zhiling, </i></span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">直領</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">) for the robe, is typical of Kucha. One can find such robes in the wall paintings in cave 8 of Kizil and cave 16 of Taitai’er which were supposedly painted during 7</span></font><sup><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">th</span></font></sup><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"> century CE. </span></font></p></li>
   <li>
    <p lang="de-DE" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">There are many examples of figures who gather both sides of everted collar together and formed a round collar (</span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><i>banling</i></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">, </span></font><font face=""><span lang="zh-CN"><font face="Arial"><span lang="ko-KR">盤領</span></font></span></font><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">). </span></font></p></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><br /></p>
  <p lang="de-DE" class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB"><u>Women’s clothing: </u></span></font></p>
  <p lang="de-DE" class="western" style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm"><font face="Arial, serif"><span lang="en-GB">Their costume of pants with tunic, as in the wall painting in cave 76 in Kizil, is similar to the Tocharian female costume. Kim supposes that this was the Aryan people’s costume before it was changed into Turkic style. Some women wore skirts, too. Clothing with everted collar and short sleeves were worn over the tunic. They were worn often in Central Asia. (Ji Ho Yi)</span></font></p>
  <style type="text/css">p { line-height: 115%; text-align: left; orphans: 2; widows: 2; margin-bottom: 0.25cm; direction: ltr; background: transparent }p.western { font-size: 12pt; so-language: de-DE }p.cjk { font-size: 12pt; so-language: zh-CN }p.ctl { font-family: "Arial"; font-size: 12pt; so-language: sa-IN }</style>
 </body>
</html>
```

The Code, I am using for PDF-Generation is:

```
byte[] bytes = html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); //String from above
String utf8EncodedString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Document annotation = Jsoup.parse(utf8EncodedString, "UTF-8");
annotation.outputSettings().escapeMode(org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.EscapeMode.extended);
annotation.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
try (ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()){
  ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();;
  renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
  SharedContext sharedContext = renderer.getSharedContext();
  sharedContext.setPrint(true);
  sharedContext.setInteractive(false);
  sharedContext.flushFonts();
  renderer.setDocumentFromString(annotation.html());
  renderer.layout();
  renderer.createPDF(out);
  response.setContentType("application/pdf");
  out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The PDF is generated just fine. However, the Han- and Korean Characters in it are being lost.

As you can see, I included the UTF-8 Font Arial. The TTF is 23 MB.
From my understanding, this should be displaying Han- and Korean Characters just fine.
I even included the font via CSS and by code (addFont). Bothy ways seem to be without any impact.

Do I miss something? Does someone understand, where my mistake is?

Please help,

Erik

Comment: *this should be displaying Han- and Korean Characters just fine.* Example codepoints please..?